# Problems installing Mac OS X Update 10.6.7

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I have Mac OS X 10.6.4 installed. I tried updating to 10.6.7 using Mac OS Software Updates, but there is a problem with installation.

The problem I face is that every time it restarts downloading from 300 MBs and even if I allow it to download completely it says

> Mac OS Update can't be saved

Where is the temporary file created which has the 300 MBs of update saved in it?

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (from what I believe) variations of this message. It could be that the integrity of the download could not be verified or there was an error with permissions.

In any way, you can [download the combo update manually from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1361), as you can with all other [support downloads](http://support.apple.com/downloads/).

I'd recommend verifying against the SHA checksum after the download.